# Can't access services on my other IP on same network interface GNS3 and Host

Tags: routing, interface, linux, gns3

I have one physical NIC that is assigned an IP address (10.14.255.240). Inside of GNS3 network simulation tool, I also have a another 'virtual' interface with another ip address (10.14.255.245). Both of these addresses are in the subnet 10.14.0.0/16 with default gateway 10.14.0.1.

My issue is that within my system the addresses seem isolated so I can't directly talk to 10.14.255.240 from 10.14.255.245 and vice versa.

However, from outside of my physical host, other devices on the subnet can talk to both 10.14.255.245 and 10.14.255.240. For example, port 80 is open on both and I can access the different webpages from my phone.

Is there a way that I can access 10.14.255.240 from inside my virtual network? Also, is there a way that I can access my virtual ip 10.14.255.245 from my host?

If it helps, my distro is Arch Linux

Comment: Actually, is this the same situation? https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50508/how-to-make-virtual-devices-on-gns3-be-able-to-ping-the-physical-host

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure pings just isn't turned on with the device you're trying to connect to?  It doesn't make any sense if devices out side of the virtual network, can access the virtual (but the machine they're passing through can't).

Do a tracert just to make sure it's going out the virtual interface.  You may also have to change the way your virtual switch or interfaces are setup in the VM settings.